# Copy file after successful build using maven

Tags: maven

I'm using `mvn install` to build the **.hpi** to my plugin for Jenkins. This puts a **.hpi** in the `target` folder.

What I would like to do is if the build is successful, copy the **hpi-file** to a specific folder. Is it possible to do both these task with one Maven command using only the terminal/command prompt?

*edit*
My POM can be seen here.
https://github.com/MarkusDNC/plot-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Please post your POM. This is typically done by deploying the file.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for the advice. Added a link to my pom.xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is now way to copy file through MVN CMD.

After that being said - You have 2 options:

1.) using a simple shell/batch step to copy.

2.) You need to Add another build step for maven but you will also need a new pom.xml file and use [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html)